# Would google consider a category page to be duplicate content ?

Tags: seo, duplicates

I have a photography website.

Photographs are taken at events. Every photograph is unique to the event. However, a popular search tool and pretty much the only SEO friendly keywords are the people's names at the event.

Each person name links to their person-name slug that shows all the person's photos across all events.

Given that a person's photos can exist on another person's page, and that a person's photos are guaranteed to live on the event page, is this duplicate content? How would I go about ensuring that I can use the SEO-friendly "person-slug" without penalizing my site for duplicate content?

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you category page has:
- unique title
- unique meta description
- unique text

This helps you to avoid duplicate content penalty.